# cgroup v2 and java 8

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, cgroups

We ran into a problem all of a sudden after switching our base jdk images and an upgrade of k8s, specifically we wanted to use `eclipse-temurin:8u312-b07-jdk`. Here is a very simplified example:

```
kubectl run jdk --image eclipse-temurin:8u312-b07-jdk --limits "memory=2Gi"
kubectl exec jdk -it -- /bin/bash
nano Dummy.java
```

with content:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Dummy {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       while(true) {
           LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
       }
   }
}
```

compile and run it:

```
javac Dummy.java
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions  -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap Dummy
```

And we get a warning:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Unable to open cgroup memory limit file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes (No such file or directory)
```

well, yes. There is no such file, but there is `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max` (cgroup v2).

Does that mean that `UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` will have no effect? It surely looks like it. I know it is deprecated and removed in `11` - that's not the point.

Thank you.

---

I did [find this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170888?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)
and it looks like I can do:

```
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxRAM=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max)  Dummy
```

but that is something I do not really like.

Comment: Cgroup v2 is supported starting from JDK 15, see [JDK-8230305](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8230305). No backports to JDK 8 or 11 yet.

Comment: IMO, `MaxRAMPercentage` is a harmful flag, since it gives a wrong perception that the JVM adapts to the given environment. It practice, it almost never does. A belief that heap size should depend on the amount of available RAM is erroneous; most often, it works the other way round. If your application perfectly works with 1GB heap, just set `-Xmx1G` and enjoy. If the heap is larger than application requires - it's the waste of memory. If it's smaller - the application basically won't work at all.

Comment: Thank you @apangin for the bug reference. As to your point: we are in a business where once a season ( think 2/3 months ), we are hit with billions of kafka messages, very, very fast. For 1 or 2 days, I need our pods to have a very big heap. We know the day when it starts, so we just restart the pods with a much bigger limit. For our business model, taking a % of RAM, makes all the sense in the world.

Comment: Your example only supports my point: you know that sometimes the application needs a huge heap - so why not setting the exact heap size with -Xmx? To make Xmx configurable from outside, set it via an environment variable. `MaxRAMPercentage` seems to me a wrong way. E.g. normally the application works with 1GB heap, so you can start it in a 2GB container with -Xmx1G. If in rare cases the application requires 60GB heap, start it with -Xmx60G and 64GB container limit. Otherwise `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50` will waste a huge amount of RAM.

Comment: @apangin I see your point, but these spikes in what we want are very costly on our provider, we we only request when needed. and btw `XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50` was just an example, we have it as `XX:MaxRAMPercentage=85/90` usually. I'll need to think about it more, may be you make sense here. thank you for the follow up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for sure something I do not like, but for images that have a `cgroup v2`, it seems like I will start it with:

```
-XX:MaxRAM=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max)
```

This way, running:

```
java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0
     -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0
     // we don't use this one, but just to look at he resident memory
     -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
     -XX:MaxRAM=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max) 
     Dummy
```

will show `top -o %MEM` as `1GB`. Not ideal, but works.

Comment: Hi Eugune, some related information for you. -XX:MaxRAMPercentage will not work with Java8 when running in a container until JDK-8230305 is backported. You can find more information here: https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/228

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same case after upgrading AKS, it appears cgroups v2 awareness has been backported to Java 8u361: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u361-relnotes.html

I haven't tested it yet but it should solve the problem.

**Update 2023-04-11**:
I have tested various Java 8 JRE images and the only ones that appear to have backported cgroups v2 support are:

- Oracle JRE 8u361 (tested with custom-built image using https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleJava/8)
- IBM Semeru (tested with [ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-8u362-b09-jre-jammy](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ibm-semeru-runtimes/open-8u362-b09-jre-jammy/images/sha256-655e4654a124de7d8747458728ed59fb022fe578f1f34c31f08a6357f073e3e2?context=explore))

In particular, [Eclipse Temurin](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/eclipse-temurin/8u362-b09-jre-alpine/images/sha256-3da0b98ae447900b7dd4e88eb6a50c766123f4fdb25d8b8a0de3ddedd86a5296?context=explore), [Azul Zulu](https://hub.docker.com/layers/azul/zulu-openjdk-debian/8u362-jre/images/sha256-e181dd50a7c9700a7934aac936ce7312970122cfbb848dca73018c7ec59841e9?context=explore), [Amazon Corretto](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/amazoncorretto/8u362-alpine3.17-jre/images/sha256-eea170e219f70e5b8beef464bd38f8a0a5ee1634013a690dad5711682e66b61d?context=explore) and [Bellsoft Liberica](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-debian/8u362-9/images/sha256-483077521b710915623a58fe426fcff329fd797b6a7b72498bc374648af836b6?context=explore) do not properly recognize cgroups v2.

Comment: OpenJDK 8u372 also support cgroup v2. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8230305