# java-8 cgroup without UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, cgroups

This continues kind of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145589/cgroup-v2-and-java-8)

I am making the same steps as there, but this time, I am dropping `UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap`:

```
java -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch Dummy &
```

And I am trying to inspect it a little:

```
jcmd 279 VM.flags
```

Among other things, I see :

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=2063597568
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.000000
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.000000
-XX:MaxHeapSize=2063597568
```

From a recommendation from [this answer from Pangin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292282/clarification-of-meaning-new-jvm-memory-parameters-initialrampercentage-and-minr), he says that:

> -XX:InitialRAMPercentage is used to calculate initial heap size when InitialHeapSize / -Xms is not set.

and :

> ... both -XX:MaxRAMPercentage and -XX:MinRAMPercentage are used to calculate maximum heap size when MaxHeapSize / -Xmx is not set

My understanding that I should *not* set `InitialHeapSize/Xms` and `MaxHeapSize/Xmx` and I *don't*, but they are set for me.

I thought that I could say `-XX:InitialHeapSize=0` and `-XX:MaxHeapSize=0`, but of course this does not work and the VM does not start.

The last point is that :

```
top -o %MEM
```

shows a 2GB of resident memory for the java process, so yeah, both `InitialRAMPercentage/MaxRAMPercentage` seems to be pointless?

---

The interesting thing here is that if I run this in `jdk-17`:

```
 java -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch Dummy &
```

then `top -o %MEM` shows `1GB`, exactly like I want it to be.

Comment: the linked question has the solution, may be someone can come up with a better one.

Comment: `MaxRAMPercentage` works as expected for me. Show the output of `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

Comment: @apangin that output is huge... [here is a link to it](https://gist.github.com/wind57/cfad67437824ddad8c41606ec5b4d766)

Comment: I mean, `PrintFlagsFinal` together with the options you test: -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0

Comment: @apangin [like this?](https://gist.github.com/wind57/cfad67437824ddad8c41606ec5b4d766)

Comment: So JVM apparently detected available RAM as 4GB. What does `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintContainerInfo` say?

Comment: @apangin `OSContainer::init: Initializing Container Support Required cgroup memory subsystem not found`. this container is running on cgroup v2, on my machine there are 16GB of RAM, since cgroup does not work (because we are on java-8), it takes 4GB, which makes sense now, right?